# Conflict with Leaflet and mmenu

Tags: jquery, css, leaflet, mmenu

I am learning about mmenu, for some reason the header bar, the one that uses to has the "Demo" word on it, isn't displayed when I render a map with Leaflet.

If you look behind the zoom in/out control of the map, appears the white "burger" icon (near the "+" sign), but the header bar.
I tryed using the z-index attribute and overriding some attibutes values without any luck.

```
.mm-menu {   
  background: #279650 !important; 
 z-index: 10 !important;
}
```

Another try I did was:

```
.header{
            background: red !important;
            z-index: 9999999;   


}
```

I will attach 2 images one with the map rendered and another without it.
Thanks in advance for any hint.

[image][image]

Answer (score 0):

It is solved, after debugging I realized that it has to do with my html id tags and neither with the leaflet nor mmenu class or id tags.

This is the html:

```
        <div id="map"></div>
    <div id="page">                     
        <div class="header">
            <a href="#menu"></a>                
        </div>                      
        <nav id="menu">
            <ul>
                <li><a href="/">Home</a></li>
                <li>
                    <span>                          
                        <a href="/item1/">Item1</a>     
                        <input type="radio" class="Check" />     
                     </span>

                </li>
                <li>    
                    <span>

                        <a href="/item2/">Item2</a>
                        <input type="radio" class="Check" />                            

                     </span>                         
                </li>                   
                <li><span>About us</span>
                    <ul>
                        <li><a href="/about/history">History</a></li>
                        <li><a href="/about/team">The team</a>
                            <ul>
                                <li><a href="/about/team/management">Management</a>                                     
                                </li>
                                <li><a href="/about/team/sales">Sales</a></li>
                                <li><a href="/about/team/development">Development</a></li>
                            </ul>
                        </li>
                        <li><a href="/about/address">Our address</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li><a href="/contact/">Contact</a></li>
            </ul>
        </nav>
    </div>
```

I have to add the following attribute value to the .header class:

```
.header{  
   position: relative;
   z-index: 15; //can be ommited
}
```

The only difference is that in Chrome the menu bar appears in front of the map control, in Firefox behind it. I decided to move down the control in order to avoid this overlapping issues (images below)
Even though it is solved I am open to suggestions.

Best!

[image]

[image]